# Replace basic authentication with Azure AD authentication in Web API

Tags: azure-active-directory, basic-authentication, exchange-basicauth

I have a Web API that used basic authorization to access the Web API from front end. So we used to pass Authorization header from Frontend Application that contains user login and password in encrypted form and sent to WEB API, where we read authorization header and fetch user login details(UserName, Password) and validate user credentials from Active directory.
Now we are implementing Azure AD integration and we are not able to send user password in Authorization header. So API fails to validate user credentials and it break the flow. Also I am getting httpcontext.current.user as null.see below code

public class UserdataController : ApiController
{
private readonly KMMContext db = new KMMContext(HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "");

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use MSAL.

A good starting point is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview

Some examples can also be found here. This one is for a javascript/nodejs client since it was not mentioned which frontend framework was used.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2

Basically your WebAPI will now be receiving a JWT token instead of the user credentials.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for replying,we have used the MSAL only. will JWT token provide me HTTPContet.current.user as not null ?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure but I think it won't. You can get the user claims to get the username though. Something like `httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name").Value`.